# ExecuteNonQuery() extremely slow when my Access DB is used from more than 1 user

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I've been looking for answers to this problem in the internet for the past 2 days, but couldn't find anything that works.

I have a database with a large number of tables and 2 of them also contain many members (about 100 000 in one case).

My Application needs to do the standard things for such Application - go through the data, write new data, delete data etc.

Everything used to work fine while we were using the initial version of the Application - 1 execute file that loads the whole table and all functionalities are available for the users. I received a task to separate the application in 2 executes, one that loads faster and has limited functions and one that has all the availabilities of the original application, but respectively has much larger loading time.

When a colleague starts the AppViewer (the restricted version) and I try to write data to the database from the full version the time it takes is ridiculous - 24-30 hours. Earlier it only took 3-4-5 minutes.
If I'm the only one, using the database - everything is fine.

The following is an example of a code that runs slowly:

```
        public OperationsRueckmeldung Speichern(OleDbConnection con, IUniversalParameter parameter)
    {
        // Informativer Rückgabe-Typ
        OperationsRueckmeldung rueckmeldung = new OperationsRueckmeldung();

        if (parameter == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Kurzname))
        {
            rueckmeldung.Nachricht = "Parameter ist null oder Parameter.Kurzname ist IsNullOrEmpty=true";
            rueckmeldung.Erfolg = -1;
            return rueckmeldung;
        }


        // Prüfen, ob der Datensatz neu ist
        bool istVorhanden = false;
        if (App.ViewModel.Identitäten.Parameter == null || App.ViewModel.Identitäten.Parameter.ID == null || App.ViewModel.Identitäten.Parameter.ID.Any() == false)
        {
            // Noch leere Datenbank
            istVorhanden = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Abgleich im Hauptspeicher
            istVorhanden = UniversalParameterIstBekannt(parameter.Kurzname);
        }

        // DB-Objekte
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            if (istVorhanden)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Parameter SET [Name]=?, [Kommentar]=?, [DomaeneID]=? WHERE Name='" + parameter.Kurzname + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Parameter ([Name], [Kommentar], [DomaeneID]) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Name]", parameter.Kurzname);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Name]", "Unbekannter Parameter");
            }
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Kommentar))
                {
                    parameter.Kommentar = string.Empty;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Kommentar]", parameter.Kommentar);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Kommentar]", "");
            }
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[DomaeneID]", parameter.Domaene.ID);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[DomaeneID]", -1);
            }

            **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

            rueckmeldung.Erfolg = 1;
            rueckmeldung.Nachricht = "Datensatz wurde erfolgreich gespeichert.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rueckmeldung.Erfolg = -1;
            rueckmeldung.Nachricht = "Datensatz konnte nicht gespeichert werden.";
            rueckmeldung.OriginalFehlermeldung = ex.Message;
        }

        return rueckmeldung;
    }
```

ExecuteNonQuery() is where the code goes from a couple of milliseconds to 10 seconds runtime.

I have tried the following suggestion to solve the problem:

adding the following code to keep the ldb file open and avoid openning it and closing it through the whole application:

```
// Keep our connection alive for the life of our application<br/>
private static OleDbCommand PermanentCommand;<br/>
<br/>
// Call this before you connect to the database for the first time<br/>
private static void KeepAlive() {<br/>
  if (PermanentCommand != null) return;<br/>
  string connectionString = "...";<br/>
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);<br/>
  conn.Open();<br/>
  PermanentCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM DummyConnection", conn);<br/>
  PermanentCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);<br/>
}<br/>
```

Unoftunately it didn't work.

Can you please help me accelerate the work of ExecuteNonQuery(). Can anyone give me a link to the code of the function?

Comment: I would like to avoid migrating to any other database :)

Comment: It's very relevant which query you're executing. Your code can either execute an insert or an update, and the update will likely take longer (the insert should be in the order of milliseconds to seconds, though). Note that you're using parameters for everything but the `WHERE` condition, which makes it a half measure and makes your code still vulnerable to SQL injection. An easy speedup of the query would be to add an index to that _Name_ column.

Comment: Access is not meant to be used in a multi-user shared environment as well as the oledb driver.  It ma work well if users are just reading values from the database, but when writing locks have to be used to prevent more than one user from accessing the same data at the same time.  The locking is what is probably slowing down the system.